# Extrema for $f(x) = x + \sin(x)$

Tags: calculus, analysis

> Find the local extrema of $f(x) = x + \sin(x)$ defined on $\mathbb{R}$.

I would like to approach this using the Mean value theorem. Any suggestions on what should i do?

Edit: As noted the function is monotonically increasing, hence i would like to show that the function does not have an local extrema using MVT.

Comment: Have you plotted the (rather particular) curve of $f$ ?

Comment: The function is monotonically increasing.

Comment: Edited the question!

Comment: Why do you think you need to use MVT?

Comment: I would like to learn how it can be applied in such a problem.

Comment: You haven't answered my question. Do you find unimportant to have a look at the graphical representation of a function under study especially when it is so particular ?

Comment: @JeanMarie Apologies for the delay. This was an old exam question, so unfortunately i would have to learn to figure this kind of stuff out without plotting the function at hand. Although afterwards looking at the graph it's quite obvious that $f$ is increasing. Thanks for pointing that out!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only need to use the MVT if you don't already know the following characterisation of monotonicity for differntiable functions:
**Theorem:** A differentiable function $g:I \to \mathbb{R}$ with $g'(x)\ge 0$, $\forall x\in I$ is increasing.
I will prove this theorem since you wish so much to use the MVT.
**Proof:** Let $x, y \in I, x<y$. From the MVT $\exists c\in (x,y)$ such that $g(y)-g(x)=(y-x)g'(c)\ge 0$, so $g(y)\ge g(x)$. Since $x$ and $y$ were arbitrarily chosen , it follows that $g$ is increasing.
Back to your problem. $f'(x)=1+\cos x \ge 0$, $\forall x\in \mathbb{R}$, so $f$ is increasing. I suppose now you should be able to finish this yourself.